# proof: $A-A(A+B)^{-1}A=B-B(A+B)^{-1}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to prove that $$A-A(A+B)^{-1}A=B-B(A+B)^{-1}B$$ and I don't know how to start. The only thing that is known is $A+B$ is nonsingular. Can someone help me to prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding $-B(A+B)^{-1}A$ on both sides gives 
$$A-(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}A=B-B(A+B)^{-1}(A+B)$$
and with $(A+B)(A+B)^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1}(A+B) = 1$

(where $1$ is the unit matrix) you have $A-A = B-B$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$(A+B)^{-1}(A+B)=I \implies (A+B)^{-1}A=I-(A+B)^{-1}B$$

and therefore

$$A-A(A+B)^{-1}A=A-A(I-(A+B)^{-1}B)=A(A+B)^{-1}B$$

and similarly since

$$(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}=I \implies B(A+B)^{-1}=I-A(A+B)^{-1}$$

we obtain

$$B-B(A+B)^{-1}B=B-(I-A(A+B)^{-1})B=A(A+B)^{-1}B$$